# How to add simple scrolling parallax effect to text in Wordpress Elementor by CSS only

Tags: css, wordpress, scroll, parallax, elementor

I would like to add a simple scrolling parallax effect to a text on a white background in Wordpress Elementor by adding some custom css. The goal is that text moves slower when scrolling. Overall it would be nice to achieve that inside Elementor editor I could add this effect on any element (text, image) by using CSS only.

Example: On http://www.thinkceu.com/ the numbers: 01, 02, 03

**I have tried:**

- Elementor tutorials: all said it is available in Elementor pro, which is not an option for me.
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rLrLJQBG_qo I have tried to add some parts from this video without any result
- https://freefrontend.com/css-scroll-effects/ I have tried to add some of them with no success
- I have also searched here on stackoverflow the existing questions, but they were all different, for example: [Wordpress - Parallax effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24872994/wordpress-parallax-effect) however the step by step guide is not available anymore

FYI: I have no coding knowledge, I have only used WordPress, but it would be a great opportunity to start learning some css. :) Thanks in advance for all your help!

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Sorry, but SO is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. You should consider reading [ask] and rewriting your question, if you can provide sample code. If you don't have a [mre] then, you can start by spending time with one of many CSS tutorials on the web.

Comment: Hello Howard, I know that the question is not a related to an exact code, but it is because it is a general question: is it possible that in Elementor I add custom css to any element (text / image) and it will scroll slower compared to the other elements and background? If not I understand that. Tutorials are only about creating the whole page in html+css, and they don't work inside Elementor.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.